# Returning Environmental Variables

Tags: django, python-3.x, environment-variables

I am working on Corey Schafer's blog tutorial and now setting up 'password reset email' using my gmail account as an email client. I want to store my email and password in an environmental variable but when I verify that the information was properly stored it returns `none`

In the terminal I used (nano .bash_profie)

```
export EMAIL_USER='email@gmail.com'
export EMAIL_PASS='password'
```

Then I verified

```
import os

user = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
password = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')

print(user)
print(password)
```

Other commenters on the tutorial suggested...

-restart editor and terminal
-Use .zshrc instead of .bash_profile

I have tried these other recommendations but still it returns `none`. I am still new to programming so any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

without '

```
export EMAIL_USER=email@gmail.com
export EMAIL_PASS=password
```

Comment: Still returns none

Answer (score 0):

Set env variables like:

> os.environ['EMAIL_USER']
>   os.environ['EMAIL_PASSWORD']

and then use with:

> os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')

Then could you try sourcing your .bash_profie and then run your python file, you must run both commands within the same shell.

> source .bash_profie
>   python yourpythonfile

Comment: I put this into the .bash_profile?os.environ['EMAIL_USER'] os.environ['EMAIL_PASSWORD']

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ubuntu, try `nano .bashrc` instead of `nano .bash_profile` then follow other instructions as you described.